# Is there a way to "force delete" an instance from memory if it is using a while loop?

Tags: c#, loops, memory, uwp, garbage-collection

Assume ClassX has a forever while loop.

Is there a way to "force stop/delete/clear memory" of a ClassX instance?

or do **I have** to stop the while loop manually within the class for GC?

Comment: Give the close command. Then in the "on-close" event start another instance via the Process Class. Note that this might cause some colissions if you use any "single instance" approach. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If you have issues with stuff not being cleaned up, you might have to learn about the Dispose() pattern and proper Exception Handling. Those two parts should solve whatever issues with leftover resources you have: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense, if you don't reference the object anymore, it will get GC'd when there is memory pressure. Just set the reference to `null` or `Dispose` if it has unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Ron - setting the reference null does NOT stop the execution of a while loop

Comment: I never said it did... I don't think that you want to stop the loop, what does the loop have to do with GC? GC will interrupt the loop and run when there is memory pressure automatically, you being in a loop doesn't suppress GC.

Comment: A code sample would be helpful here. It sounds like you're calling a method of a class which never returns, and you want to add some kind of timeout to the method call. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ron - Waiting for GC to stop the loop isn't a good solution... I've tried this and several minutes later the while loop is still going (and no reference to the class instance)

Comment: But why are you relating GC to stopping the loop at all?

Comment: @Rufus - I'm testing it with a very simple ClassX that starts a while loop within it (calls an async method using Task.Delay and while loop) - I create an instance of ClassX - the while loop obviously starts --- I null out the refernce to ClassX instance -- still the loop runs [as it should, but I'm lazy and just want it to stop when I null out instance to class that uses it]

Comment: @Jon - I come from a platform where you could simply restart your game (it clears up everything, eventually freeing resources) - side benefit of not having to null stuff out for GC - I assumed GC was needed for what I wanted.  idk.... I don't want to confuse I just want to know if you can stop a while loop (and eventually free it up for GC) - without 'manually' stopping the loop.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in the design of the `ClassX` class, if a Task should be cancelled, it should be able to take (and handle) a `CancellationToken` so that the calling method can cancel the operation. The only other possibility is to spawn off a new thread and abort it, I don't know if using a cancel-able task inside another task would kill the inner task. Any way you look at it this is unrelated to GC.

Comment: I THINK I'M NOT MAKING SENSE BECAUSE WHAT I WANT ISN'T POSSIBLE.   I just wanted a magic button to stop all threads/loops simply - I did this before with restarting the game - not an option now.  So I will code in the overhead to properly stop/restart all my code.

Comment: Sample incoming. Sec.

Comment: What problem are you encountering that the class is still in memory? Why can you not just let GC do it's job? Is something bad happening? Typically you don't have control of objects for which you don't have a reference.

Comment: @Rufus - I'm assuming it is still in memory because of the while loop.  (I was under the impression that if a variable wasn't referenced GC would take affect, but apparently that isn't the case if you have a while loop executing within that instance.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of your question seems to be asking how to exit out of a continuous loop in an asynchronous context. The solution to your problem is [cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

A simple example might be the following:

```
class Caller
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private Runner _runner;

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            _runner = new Runner();
            await _runner.DoWorkAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) when (_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // this will ignore the exception when cancellation is requested. it might be useful in a reset scenario.
            // otherwise, don't try/catch and just let the exception bubble up
        }
        finally
        {
            _runner = null;
            _cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}

class Runner
{
    public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The caller's `StartAsync()` will create a `CancellationTokenSource`, and start the `DoWorkAsync()` method of the runner by passing in the cancellation token.

The caller's `DoWorkAsync()` method will, on every iteration of the loop, ask the token to throw an exception if the source has requested cancellation. Note that cancellation is cooperative - you have to check if cancellation has been requested for it to work. You should also pass the cancellationToken into any async methods that accept it, as I've demonstrated with `Task.Delay`.

Note that I've used `catch (OperationCanceledException) when (_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` in the `StartAsync()` method. Since this is a reset scenario, I don't want the exception to bubble up and crash the application, but I don't want to catch similar exceptions caused by something other than our cancellation request, hence the `when ....` part. How you want to handle these things depends on you, I just figured I'd demonstrate this at the same time in case it's useful in your scenario.

Now, when we call `Stop()`, it simply flags the cancellation request on the token, so that our co-operative cancellation code will know it's time to cancel the execution.

Comment: So if I want to restart the game.  I can call the cancel tokens right before I reassign the 'game variable' and it will cancel out the async looping of the previous instantiate?

Comment: Yeah. You know when you want to do that, presumably, so you can call the cancel method when you want your loops to stop. After the cancellation is completed (`finally`), you can do whatever you want to do next.

Comment: I just want to stop all the exeucting of the previous game 'session'  - ty for the help.  I just wish it was easier (a lot to keep track of - to stop before restarting)

Comment: Note that CancellationTokenSource has a static method for creating one from [one or more existing cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netframework-4.7.2) - not sure if it might be useful to you. Also, a single cancellation token can be used for many methods, etc.

Comment: THANK YOU - that makes cancellation tokens a lot more appealing!